# Einstein summation confusion

Tags: summation, tensors

I was trying to evaluate the following expression:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{u_iu_i}}.$$

I know the author used this as short notation for

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{u_1^2+u_2^2+u_3^2}}$$

and I always thought of it as this expression. Now, I can rewrite

$$u_i^{-1/2}u_i^{-1/2}.$$

Using the summation convention (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation)

$\sum_{i=1}^{3}c_ix^i=c_ix^i$

this would result in:

$u_i^{-1/2}u_i^{-1/2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}u_i^{-1/2}u_i^{-1/2}=u_1^{-1/2}u_1^{-1/2}+u_2^{-1/2}u_2^{-1/2}+u_3^{-1/2}u_3^{-1/2}.$

Which is clearly not what was intended by the author.

> My question: Which intrepretation is right and which is wrong? I would be glad > if someone could give a trustable source.

Comment: Seems as the sum is supposed to be taken under the square root. In this case, everything is fine (in an orthonormal base).

Comment: The problem is that it is not allowed to commute an operation of summation and an operation of taking the inverse.

Comment: @JeanMarie Could you explain that further? In my opinion, the interpretation with summing under the square roots and the way proposed in the answers cannot be defined for arbitrary expressions, without alot of verbal explanations.

Answer (score 5):

Think of it like this(*)

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{u_i u_i}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\sum u_i u_i}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{u1^2 + u_2^2 + u_3^2}}
$$

(*)**Important:** There is however an abuse of notation here: $x_ix_i$ does not expand to $x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2$ using Einstein's convention, because it violates one rule: one upper index sums with one and only one lower index. In this expression there're only lower indices! You can fix this by introducing a Kronecker delta

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{u_i\delta^{ij}u_j}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{u1^2 + u_2^2 + u_3^2}}
$$

Answer (score -1):

$u^iu_i$ is shortened for $\sum_i u_iu_i$ ; which is $u_1^2+u_2^2+u_3^2$ when we implicitly have $i\in\{1,2,3\}$

Thus $(u^iu_i)^{-1/2} = (u_1^2+u_2^2+u_3^2)^{-1/2}$ because we resolve the Einstein notation before applying the exponent *to* the series.

This is quite distinct from $u^iv_i$ in which the exponent *is* the bound variable *of* the series.

---

PS: Also note that when using Einstein notation $(u^iv_i)^2 \neq (u^i)^2(v_i)^2$ as the square of a series is not equal to a series of squares.

$$(u^iv_i)^2=  (u_1v_1+u_2v_2+u_3v_3)^2~\neq~ (u_1+u_2+u_3)^2(u_1+u_2+u_3)^2=(u^i)^2(v_i)^2$$

Similarly $(u^iu_i)^{-1/2}\neq (u^i)^{-1/2}(u_i)^{-1/2}$.   Exponents do not distribute over series.

Comment: so how do you define the summation convention for an arbitrary expression $f(i,j)$ without knowing its exact form.